# Allowing An Admin to Assign User's To A Sub-admin in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a bloglike application which includes features based around different tiers of admins.

I have a main admin who I want to give the ability to turn a user into a subadmin, which will be a type of admin who has access to some admin features but not all.

Currently I have this _users partial which I use in a view to display all users to the admin:

```
<li>
  <%= link_to user.name, user %>
| <%= pluralize(user.how_many_new_posts?, "unsubmitted daily post") %>   
<% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
    | <%= link_to "delete account", user, method: :delete,
                                  data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

This will render the name of each user, how many unsubmitted posts they have, and the option to delete the user.

I want to include another option here, a way of clicking a button to make the specified user a subadmin. Once this button is clicked it should give the admin the ability to assign other users to this subadmin, so that they can monitor them in the same way as the above partial. I assume this will require some new kind of partial, but I'm not totally sure how it would work. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a model say `Role` which `has_many` users and `User` `belongs_to` `Role` or whatever relationship you prefer.
You may have difderent `roles` in there..
You can then manage there accessibilities/abilities based on their role designing your own or there are gems at your disposal e.g. [`cancancan`](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan)

Then, in your view you can provide a dropdown list for available `roles` and change the `role_id` on `submit`.